# Read from AWS S3 with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm using `spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3` installed in a AWS EC2 with Linux Red Hat 9 and I would like to read and write data from S3.

- I can access S3 buckets using Boto3, s3fs, etc. So, it not a matter of having right permissions.
- I have tried already all the possible combinations o Hadoop hadoop-aws y aws-jdks versions possible.

Please, can someone help?

**First I tried something like this:**

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("aws_s3") \
            .config('spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage', False) \
            .getOrCreate()\

spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", "my_key_id")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", "my_secret_key")
```

**Then I added other options I saw in Stackoverflow**

```py
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "mykey")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "mysecret")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "eu-west-3.amazonaws.com")
```

**Other options I tried are:**

- `pyspark --pakages "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.5, org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.3.5"`
- `pyspark --pakages "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1, org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.3.1"`
- Etc.

However, the most I got is the *access denied* message, but as I previously said, I can access the buckets in other different ways

Comment: What does the s3 url look like in your pyspark code? is it `s3://....` or `s3a://...`? If it's the former, try setting the properties with `.s3.` instead of `.s3a.`

Comment: Why EC2 instead of EMR?

Comment: I'm trying to access s3a://bucket/...

Comment: @aga if your EC2 instance has correct IAM role you can change your auth type and try, instead of secrets

Comment: @RonakJain I use a pass role with other applications such as s3fs and it works perfectly well

Comment: Afraid you are trying to configure the connector by copying stack overflow posts from 10 years ago. Better to read the hadoop s3a connector documentation than copy the mistakes of others

Answer (score 0):

Well guys,
I'm going to partially answer my own question.

In my case I have implemented a Multifactor authentication (MFA) which make access to S3 even more complicated.

```
    # Set up your AWS credentials
    aws_access_key = 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY'
    aws_secret_key = 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
    mfa_serial_number = 'MFA_SERIAL_NUMBER'

    # Prompt to request a MFA token
    mfa_token = input("Enter your MFA token: ")

    # Set up Spark session
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
     .appName("S3_Parquet") \
     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl",  "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", aws_access_key) \
     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", aws_secret_key) \
     .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.2,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.12.115") \
     .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider.params", f"mfa_serial={mfa_serial_number},mfa_token={mfa_token}") \
     .getOrCreate()


     # Read Parquet file from S3 using Spark
     file_path = "s3a://path/to/part- 00000-000-1111-4444-5555-6677889900.c111.snappy.parquet"

     df = spark.read.parquet(file_path)

     # Show dataframe
     df.show()
```

This piece of code prompts the user to introduce a MFA_TOKEN_CODE generated by a MFA associated application.

The key is to choose a compatible combination of "spark.jars.packages". In my case it was "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.2,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.12.115"